# VHDL FSM Implementation using port mapping

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

I'm trying to implement VHDL code using `Finite state machine` and Port mapping to components

Does any one have an idea how to do it, since it isn't allowed to include the port mapping inside the process statement?

```
------ and_2.vhd (component): --------- 
LIBRARY ieee; 
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
--------------------------------------- 
ENTITY and_2 IS 
PORT ( a, b: IN STD_LOGIC; 
y:OUT STD_LOGIC); 
END and_2; 
--------------------------------------- 
ARCHITECTURE and_2 OF and_2 IS 
BEGIN 
y <= a AND b; 
END and_2; 
---------------------------------------
LIBRARY ieee; 
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all; 
USE work.my_data.all;
ENTITY FSM_PORTMAPP IS
PORT(
   clk,reset : IN STD_LOGIC;
   A,b,c,d: IN STD_LOGIC;
    x: out STD_LOGIC
);
END FSM_PORTMAPP; 
ARCHITECTURE Flow OF FSM_PORTMAPP IS 
----------------------- 
COMPONENT and_2 IS 
PORT ( a, b: IN STD_LOGIC; y: OUT STD_LOGIC); 
END COMPONENT; 
-----------------------
TYPE state IS (state0, state1, state2); 
SIGNAL pr_state, nx_state: state;
signal y,z :std_logic;
BEGIN
U1:and_2 PORT MAP(a,b ,y);
U2:and_2 PORT MAP(c,d,z);
U3:and_2 PORT MAP(y,z,x);
process(clk,reset)
BEGIN 
IF (reset='1') THEN 
        pr_state <= state0;
ELSIF (clk'EVENT AND clk='1') THEN 
        pr_state <= nx_state; 
END IF;
end process;
process(pr_state)
BEGIN 
case pr_state IS
WHEN state0 => 
nx_state <= state1;
WHEN state1=> 
nx_state <= state2;
WHEN state2 => 
nx_state <= state0;
END CASE;
end process;
END Flow;
-------------------------------------------------
```

That is an example for declaration, I want to implement three states, with each state implementing one component.

Comment: What do you mean by "each state implementing one component"? What do you expect to happen in each state?

Comment: each state implement one component instant..  state0 implement u1, state1 implement u2 ,state2 implement u3.

Comment: What action do you expect to occur? What values do you expect to change? What signals do you want to drive? You haven't stated what function you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: my target is how to learn how to use port mapping with Finite state machine and i take this code as example ,,,,

Comment: Assume that i want to add 4 signals a,b,c,d and i want to add them using adder_2 which adds to signals only ...and i want to implement them in adder tree format so in the first state a, and b will be added and saved at signal y and c and d will be added as well and saved at signal z then in the next state y and z will be added and and the result will be at the the output x..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, think of component instantiation and port mapping as *wiring circuit components*, not performing operations. The mapping itself does not perform any operation - the logic in the component combined with the signals driven into the component achieve that. This is also why you can't map a component in a process - wiring is a fixed connection, not something that you can perform as a runtime operation. It's not *executed code* - it's concurrent logic.

In your example code, there are three instances of the component `and_2`, outside of any process. This mapping is basically what you need (provided you change the component and signal types to your particular function). *Then*, in your state machine, you can drive the inputs selectively, or read the outputs, or whatever you need. You will probably need some intermediate signals, and you would need to change your wiring around, and what you will most likely get on your first attempt is problematic code with latches where you don't want them and nice things like that. What you can do *instead* is just register the adder outputs:

```
U1 : adder_2 port map (a, b, y);
U2 : adder_2 port map (c, d, z);
U3 : adder_2 port map (y_r, z_r, x);

adder_regs : process (clk)
begin
  if rising_edge(clk) then
    y_r <= y;
    z_r <= z;
  end if;
end process adder_regs;
```

Or is there some other reason you're trying to do it the way you are?

Comment: Thanks alot fru1tbat for your valuable explanation ........ i have a big code and i wounder if i can send it to you to take your opinion in it or not.....Best regards

Comment: I'm not sure that would be a good idea. If you have specific problems, you're better off asking here anyway -- the community is very knowledgeable.

Comment: DO you have any material of working with port mapping and it's using with finite state machines?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're looking for. There is nothing special about an FSM - it's just a process or collection of processes inside an architecture like anything else. There really isn't any such specific concept. Maybe you need a tutorial on FSMs, or a beginner's guide to VHDL? There are plenty out there to choose from.

Comment: I tried to put hte code i'm working on ..but it's too big soi put it here..https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B2vrK3S8X6c1TlBuMkw0QTY1OHc...here you can see what's i'm working on

Comment: ERROR:Xst:528 - Multi-source in Unit <Multiplier> on signal <mul1_next<0><29>>; this signal is connected to multiple drivers.     i get hundreds of errors like that